# Reason for strange gap in the plot

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I have this plot of Depths vs time:[image]
This plot has a strange gap at the start of May.

[image]

I checked the data but there are no NAs or Nans or no missing data.
This is a time series of regular interval of 15 minutes

I cannot give the dataset here since it contains 10,000 rows.
Can somebody please give suggestions as what possibly it can be?

I am using the following plotting code:

```
   library(zoo)
   z=read.zoo("data.txt", header=TRUE)
   temp=index(z[,1])
   m=coredata(z[,1])
x=0.001
p=rep.int(x,length(temp))
png(filename=paste(Name[k],"_mean1.png", sep=''), width= 3500, height=1600, units="px")
par(mar=c(13,13,5,3),cex.axis= 2.5, cex.lab=3, cex.main=3.5, cex.sub=5)
plot(temp,m, xlab="Time", ylab="Depth",type='l', main=Name[k])
symbols(temp,m,add=TRUE,circles=p, inches=1/15, ann=F, bg="steelblue2", fg=NULL)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Could you post the data to something like pastebin?

Comment: have you inspected the data at the times in question? Does the same problem occur when you subset only the times around the problematic area? This will be (almost) impossible to answer without at least a subset of the data, given that it is a data-specific problem!

Comment: Can you please give me the link where I can upload the data?
Or is there a way on SO to upload the data?

Comment: I did inspect the data before coming here and could not find anything.
I posted this over here with hope that somebody may have came across such a problem before and would be able to give me some useful suggestion.

Comment: what is the data source? Is it from a machine that is possibly faulty?

Comment: You're going to have to provide more info - what is the plotting call being used? Base? Ggplot? Some other time-series plot? What is the type of the data points? What are the classes/types of the date/time values being plotted on the x-axis? What is the specific values of the date/time where the graph goes funny? Etc etc etc.

Comment: @John-Yes the data is from the machine, it can be a systematic error, but I'm not able to figure out how is it happening although the data is continuous throughout.

Comment: Clearly, it is a data problem so you will have to upload at least some of the data for a solution to be found. A gist on github.com  would be a possibility for uploading the problem data

Answer (score 7):

Okay, here's a guess from what you have posted.

I'm guessing there is no data for a period right at the start of May where the 'gap' in question pops up. There are no NAs because there just aren't any lines of data for this period at all. There is still a thin black line drawn to the plot by this line of code which links the 'gap' in data...

```
plot(temp,m, xlab="Time", ylab="Depth",type='l', main=Name[k])
```

...but there are no blue symbols (circles) plotted close together enough to make it look like a continuous blue line. The blue symbols being plotted with the below code, over the top of the existing plot:

```
symbols(temp,m,add=TRUE,circles=p, inches=1/15, ann=F, bg="steelblue2", fg=NULL)
```

I suggest instead of plotting a line and then plotting symbols over the top of it that you just plot a thick blue line to start with like:

```
plot(temp,m, xlab="Time", ylab="Depth",type='l', main=Name[k],lwd=5,col="steelblue2")
```