# R base graphic: How to adjust gap size in the timeseries plot?

Tags: r, plot

I saw this kind of questions about ggplot2 or other libraries, but cannot find one about the base graphics.

[image]

The data used for the plot does not have blank rows with NAs,

but they appear in the plot automatically.

1) How can I remove the blank space in the plot?
2) Can I manually adjust the gap size in the plot?

** edit

**
I provide an example code with smaller # of data, but it can show you the exact problem.

```
x = c(seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct("2018-07-27 00:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d 
%H:%M:%S"),
             to = as.POSIXct("2018-07-27 10:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d 
%H:%M:%S"),
             by = "1 hour"),
  seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct("2018-09-01 00:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d 
%H:%M:%S"),
             to = as.POSIXct("2018-09-01 08:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d 
%H:%M:%S"),
             by = "1 hour"))

y1 = 20 + rnorm(20)
y2 = 10 + rnorm(20)
y3 = 5 + rnorm(20)
date0601 = as.POSIXct("2018-06-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
date0930 = as.POSIXct("2018-09-30", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
dates = seq.POSIXt(from = date0601, to = date0930, by = "15 days")
lab_dates = strftime(dates, format = "%m-%d")

par(mfrow = c(1, 1),
mar = c(5.1, 5.1, 2.1, 5.1))
plot(x, y1,
 axes = FALSE, xaxs = "i",yaxs = "i",
 xlab = "Date", ylab = "Moisture Content (%)", ylim = c(0, 35),
 type = "l", lwd = 2, col = "black", cex.lab = 2.0, cex.axis = 2.0, mgp = 
c(3, 0, 0))
points(x, y2, type = "l", lwd = 2, col = "red")
bot = c(x[11], x[12])
top = c(10, 28)
rect(bot[1], top[1], bot[2], top[2], border = "white",
 col = "white") # rectangular to mask gap interval

axis(1, at = dates, labels = lab_dates, 
 cex.axis = 2.0, mgp = c(0, 1.0, 0.0))
axis(2, at = seq(0, 35, 10), labels = seq(0, 35, 10),
 cex.axis = 2.0, mgp = c(10, 0.5, 0.0))

par(new = TRUE)
plot(x, y3, type = "h", lwd = 2, col = "blue", ylim = c(0, 40),
 axes = FALSE, xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", xlab = "", ylab = "")
axis(4, at = seq(0, 40, 10), labels = seq(0, 40, 10),
 cex.axis = 2.0, mgp = c(10, 1.0, 0.0))
```

note that four lines from "bot = c~~" are for masking the gap in the plot.

Without the code, a line for each dataset will appear in the gap in the plot.

Comment: Without seeing the data, I can't help but disagree and say that there is "obviously" a gap somehow in the data. If you make this question reproducible, we might be able to help. This includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages) and sample data (e.g., `dput(head(x))`). Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: The default R line plot joins points unless they are `NA`, so I too cast some doubt on this output. `plot(x=c(1:4,10:12), y=1:7, type="l")` for example . Are you just plotting many points rather than a line? Try adding the `type="l"` argument as an initial check.

Comment: I have seen a similar issue many years ago with this plot - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255210/reason-for-strange-gap-in-the-plot/11255913 - which might be the same (or at least a similar) issue you are experiencing.

Comment: I edited my question to give an short example code. Thank you.